# Subpages and Images show 404 on my Digitalocean + Statamic Dev Environment

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx, content-management-system, statamic

I am currently setting up a dev environment for a small relaunch of a website. For that matter, I set up a new socket with needed php version, apache, nginx, mysql and pulled the current git version of the web. But all I can see is the content of the main page, even the links to some subpage dont work. The web uses "Statamic" as backend. Did I forget something basic? Thanks in advance for your help.

There are no ngnix error logs, I also tought of having to reinstall statamic somehow, but its not mentioned in the package.json of the original website.

Edit:

Here is my nginx config file for the domain:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/xxx/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name xxx.tanja-kobler.com;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
 }

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
}
```

**UPDATE & SOLUTION:**

I deleted apache2. But the main problem was this line in the ngnix configuration:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

I changed it to:

```
try_files /static${uri}_${args}.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

not it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Your question is very general, it is not possible to simulate what you are trying to do in this way. Edit the post including the nginx and statamic settings, which are usually in config/statamic/general.php. Remember that you must provide us with a minimum reproducible example to contribute to the community with your question.

Comment: Hi @RamonSoarez and thanks for your comment. I couldnt find a general.php file, so i added the nginx.conf and a screenshot of the files I could. Is there something that can help?

Comment: Hello @tanja-k, you provided the nginx config and not the website, you must provide the configuration of your website than is in nginx in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ folder or apache in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ can be the file 000-default.conf or default.conf , if you have configured it with domain you may have another configuration active for the domain with the name domain.conf

Comment: Hello @RamonSoarez, thank you so much for your patience with me and sorry for being such a noob. I added the three config files (1: ngnix config for my project, 2. ngnix default config, apache default config). I hope that helps.

Comment: Update: I did remove apache2 (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176964/permanently-removing-apache2) ) because I think that it could have interfeared with nginx. Still there is no noticeable change :(

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the APP_URL matches your URL name.
These are also the commands I ran at deployment time.

php artisan optimize:clear

php please static:clear

php please glide:clear

php please assets:generate-presets

php please assets:meta

php please stache:refresh

If you are using OPCache

sudo -S service php8-fpm reload

php please static:warm

Comment: When answering a question, make it clear what each command does, this will help other collaborators in the community.